# Executing Java 5 Code With Java 6

Tags: java, compilation, java-6, java-5

Is there *any* way I can run class files (i.e. with main as the entry point) on JDK 6 that were compiled with Java 5?

Comment: You cannot go backward to run 6 on 5 or 4, but it should be forward compatible.  Like running i386 code on i686.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. Old java code can be executed on newer JVMs, but not the other way around.

You'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, that should work with no trouble at all.  Why, are you having a problem?  Be more specific.

Comment: I am not having problems doing it; admittedly I have not tried it yet.  I wanted to make sure this is possible before I start heading down that road.  I just remember having problems running Java 5 code on different versions, I don't remember if it was 6; I guess I was trying to run 5 on 1.4.

Comment: if you want to allow your code to run on older versions of java you can give javac the -target parameter. See http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Problem is, that won't work if you're using any of the newer language features.